# Caclulate $\frac{\arcsin x}{x} ; x \to 0$

Tags: calculus

If I know $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$ when $x \to 0$, how do I find the value of $$\frac{\arcsin x}{x} ; x \to 0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $y=\arcsin x$. Then
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arcsin x}x=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac y{\sin y}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Since the $\arcsin$ is the inverse function of $\sin$ and since $\sin x\sim_0 x$ (using that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$) then we have also $\arcsin x\sim_0 x$ and the result follows.

We can also find the limit using the l'Hôpital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arcsin x}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $\arcsin x=h\implies x=\sin h$

and as $x\to0,h\to\arcsin 0=0$